# WebExtension overriding new tab doesn't focus omnibox on Firefox Quantum

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a very simple webextension that, when new tab is clicked, it's overriden by an html that displays a site inside an iframe.

Relevant aprt of the manifest.json:

```
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "background.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs"]
```

and background.html is as simple as:

```
<html>
    <iframe src="https://app.everydaycheck.com">
        everydayCheck
    </iframe>
</html>
```

This extension works smoothly for Chrome, you click newtab and while the new tab is displaying/loading the site you can immediately start typing in the omnibox for whichever google search you want. However, that's not the case in Firefox.

While in Firefox 56, the omnibox was populated by the local url of the web extension, Firefox 57 doesn't show it anymore, but it doesn't autofocus the omnibox either.

Looking at https://github.com/cadeyrn/newtaboverride/blob/70d2186b0eb7f8f5ddaaefb4f51b5332127f4ba2/src/js/core/newtab.js#L94 it does seem it should work though.

One thing I have noticed is, if I have focused the omnibox before I click new tab, then the resulting new tab has the omnibox focused. However, if I have been browsing through a website and click new tab, it doesn't.

I don't think the application is "stealing focus" from the omnibox because before the site has loaded, the omnibox has already lost focus.

Does anyone have any idea of how to go about this rather simple and obvious webextension?

By the way, you can try if it works for you: 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/everydaycheck-do-it-every-day/

Thank you.